# C++, SDL, libcaca - How to disable playing videos in terminal over ssh

Tags: c++, ssh, terminal, sdl

The title is kind of strange, I know but that really is my case:

I wrote an application in C++ that uses [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) to render bitmaps on screen.
Some of the code:

```
myScreen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);

bitmap = SDL_LoadBMP(filename.c_str());

SDL_BlitSurface(bitmap, NULL, myScreen, NULL);
SDL_Flip(myScreen);
SDL_FreeSurface(bitmap);
```

When I'm on the device it works great displaying bitmaps/video on the screen connected with HDMI (My device is a Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 15.10 on it).

Now when I execute this on the same device but I'm connected via ssh (from terminal) the video is displayed **in my terminal** (from what I found it seems to be [libcaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libcaca) that's responsible.

Laugh it up, but then please tell me:

How can I disable it and display the video via HDMI screen connected to my device?

[Link to big buck bunny in terminal](http://postimg.org/image/xxjrqj8pb/).

Comment: "When I'm on the device" vs. "when I execute this on the same device but I'm connected via ssh (from terminal)": what do you mean in precise technical terms (different environment variables, pty, etc.)? Does your application think it's running without access to a graphical display? I would try to find out what goes wrong by checking SDL errors first and debugging from the beginning to after SDL_SetVideoMode as a last resort.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQUsingSDL

Comment: Hah. It's aalib, not libcaca. I should have checked that. Thanks @genpfault. I will check on monday if setting default video driver works and result is visible on HDMI. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in via `ssh`, set your DISPLAY environment variable to the local display before running the program. It should then choose a local video display driver and display over the HDMI attached to your laptop,

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ ./your-sdl-program
```

or one-off,

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 ./your-sdl-program
```